# AspNetCore.Reporting cashing issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, report, rdlc

I try to reporting in asp core 5 app using AspNetCore.Reporting library,
here my code:

```
        public IActionResult Print()
        {
            LocalReport newReport = new LocalReport(_env.WebRootPath + "/Reports/RenterAmount.rdlc");
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            parameters.Add("Name", "Here Name");
            var viewReport = newReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, 1, null, "");
            return File(viewReport.MainStream, "application/pdf");

        }
```

now when use it as it is there cause cashing issue when use more than one report in other actions, I do some search about issue, there is some solutions said: should use execute report into separate process like Tmds.ExecFunction library, but there is not easy to use it in asp core application or I don't have an experience of usage, or use report execute into console application but also I can't do that and execute console app in asp core application, please help me in clear full solution that fix AspNetCore.Reporting cashing issue in asp.net core app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Moved to use ReportViewerCore.NETCore library